# Excel - assemble folder path by skipping empty cells

Tags: excel

For processing with other application I Need to prepare a Folder path.

The desired result is the green column. There should be a Formula doing something like "take a step to the Right - go upwards until you find a value" then put together with the value in yellow cell + do same with next column.

In Brief: a) Yellow is Achor  b) orange columns B/C/D are user's entries c) green is desired result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this once with an xml that I needed to represent as a flat file. If you copy those values down to fill blank cells, you could just have a column that concatenates each column to the left. But that's not very programmatic and a bit labor intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some VBA that will do what I explained above but automatically instead. Might be clunky but it works in my tests. It was easier to fill in the blanks than to go down and left and right and program all that if/then logic.

[Turns this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E24IF.png)
[Into this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJPfz.png)

```
Sub pathMaker()

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim lcol As Integer
Dim firstrow As Integer
Dim headers As String
Dim resultcol As Integer


lcol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
lrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
resultcol = lcol + 1
headers = MsgBox("Does your data contain a header row?", 
vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Headers")

' Determines whether to make the first or second row a 
'filepath
If headers = vbYes Then
    firstrow = 2
    'lrow = lrow - 1
    Else
    firstrow = 1
End If

'Goes through each row a column at a time and copies the 
'filepath element down (which results 
'in an extra row at the end, but it isn't included in the 
'list of filepaths later so just ignore)   

For c = 1 To lcol
   Select Case c
   Case 1
    For r = firstrow To lrow
        If IsEmpty(Cells(r, c).Offset(1, 0)) = True Then
            Cells(r, c).Offset(1, 0) = Cells(r, c)
        End If
        Next r
   Case Is > 1
    For r = firstrow To lrow
        If IsEmpty(Cells(r, c).Offset(1, 0)) = True Then
            If Cells(r, c).Offset(1, -1) = Cells(r, 
c).Offset(0, -1) Then
                Cells(r, c).Offset(1, 0) = Cells(r, c)
            End If
        End If
        Next r
   End Select
   Next c
'Concatenates populated cells into filepaths in the last 
'column plus one   
For ir = firstrow To lrow
    For ic = 1 To lcol
        If IsEmpty(Cells(ir, ic)) = False Then
        Cells(ir, resultcol) = Cells(ir, resultcol) & 
Cells(ir, ic) & "\"
        End If
    Next ic
Next ir

End Sub
```

Hope it helps! Good luck.